# How to match xml attribute name by its value and display that element only from list of elements

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am new to xslt. I want to display only matched item(s) from xml list.
using xslt transformation.

in this case I only want to display attribute with name of "one" and "two"

Thanks in advance.

xml code:

```
<myparent>
    <mychild>
        <mygrndchild name="a" parent="1" >                       
            <attribute name="one" value="1"/>
            <attribute name="two" value="1"/>
            <attribute name="three" value="1"/>
            <attribute name="four" value="0"/>            
        </mygrndchild>      
        <mygrndchild name="b" parent="1" >                       
            <attribute name="one2" value="2"/>
            <attribute name="two2" value="3"/>
            <attribute name="three2" value="4"/>
            <attribute name="four2" value="5"/>            
        </mygrndchild>
    </mychild>
</myparent>
```

xslt code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <!--suppresses attribute in list-->
    
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() "/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
     <xsl:template match="/parent">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>


     <xsl:template match="/child">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="grandchild"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
     
     <xsl:template match="/grandchild">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="/attribute">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[. = 'one']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/attribute">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[. = 'two']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this code outputs xml as is.

expected results:

```
<myparent>
    <mychild>
        <mygrndchild name="a" parent="1" >                       
            <attribute name="one" value="1"/>           
        </mygrndchild>      
        <mygrndchild name="a" parent="1" > 
            <attribute name="two" value="1"/>   
        </mygrndchild>
    </mychild>
</myparent>
```

I appreciate your help in advance.
this is for me learn some xml transformation.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the transformation result you want to achieve. As for your code, all the leading `/` in match attributes doesn't belong there as it only would match root elements/top level elements. So you want e.g. `match="attribute"` instead of `match="/attribute"`. And if you want to compare a node to a string use e.g. `= 'one'`, not ` = one`, as the latter would try to select an element named `one`. Whether any of your code as currently written is needed is not clear, show us the result you want.

Comment: I said please edit the question, don't try to present code samples in comments. And where is the requirement "I only want to display attribute with name of "one" and "two"" reflected in that result?

Comment: I did thanks.

thats exactly what I want.

Comment: I realize that xsl doesn't remove unwated stuff however it can copy stuff needed.

thats basically what I want to achieve, to copy only attributes with name = 'one'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want something like

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:param name="att-list" as="xs:string*" select="'one', 'two'"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="attribute[not(@name = $att-list)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online fiddle using Saxon HE 12](https://martin-honnen.github.io/cheerpj3-saxonhe12-fiddle/?code=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22att-list%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring*%22%20select%3D%22%27one%27%2C%20%27two%27%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22attribute%5Bnot%28%40name%20%3D%20%24att-list%29%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3Cmyparent%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmychild%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmygrndchild%20name%3D%22a%22%20parent%3D%221%22%20%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22one%22%20value%3D%221%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22two%22%20value%3D%221%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22three%22%20value%3D%221%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22four%22%20value%3D%220%22%2F%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmygrndchild%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmygrndchild%20name%3D%22b%22%20parent%3D%221%22%20%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22one2%22%20value%3D%222%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22two2%22%20value%3D%223%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22three2%22%20value%3D%224%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22four2%22%20value%3D%225%22%2F%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmygrndchild%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmychild%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fmyparent%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML).

If you are really using an XSLT 2 processor replace the `xsl:mode` declaration with the identity transformation template (the first one in your posted code).

Or based on the wanted result, assuming XSLT 3, you could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="att-list" as="xs:string*" select="'one', 'two'"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="mychild">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="snapshot(.//attribute[@name = $att-list])/ancestor::mygrndchild"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online fiddle using Saxon HE 12.](https://martin-honnen.github.io/cheerpj3-saxonhe12-fiddle/?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22att-list%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring*%22%20select%3D%22%27one%27%2C%20%27two%27%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22mychild%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy-of%20select%3D%22snapshot%28.%2F%2Fattribute%5B%40name%20%3D%20%24att-list%5D%29%2Fancestor%3A%3Amygrndchild%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3Cmyparent%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmychild%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmygrndchild%20name%3D%22a%22%20parent%3D%221%22%20%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22one%22%20value%3D%221%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22two%22%20value%3D%221%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22three%22%20value%3D%221%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22four%22%20value%3D%220%22%2F%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmygrndchild%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmygrndchild%20name%3D%22b%22%20parent%3D%221%22%20%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22one2%22%20value%3D%222%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22two2%22%20value%3D%223%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22three2%22%20value%3D%224%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cattribute%20name%3D%22four2%22%20value%3D%225%22%2F%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmygrndchild%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmychild%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fmyparent%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML)

Comment: okay, changed to use identity transformation, and it worked.

you are so amazing.  @Martin Honnen

Comment: when I use Java code I get transformation configuration exception on ``` <xsl param ... />,

like :


Syntax error in ''one','two' '.

Do you know why it works online and not on my local when using java.

Comment: @NeoSono, you tagged the question as `xslt-2.0` which should support the used syntax `<xsl:param name="att-list" as="xs:string*" select="'one', 'two'"/>`. Note, however, that most existing software stacks, like for instance the Java JRE/JDK, only come with an XSLT 1.0 processor. In the Java world this is easily correctly by putting Saxon HE Java (currently supported versions are 11 and 12) on the class path, you can find it on Maven https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE or Github https://github.com/Saxonica/Saxon-HE/releases/tag/SaxonHE12-4.

Comment: working fine with dependency. Much appreciation.